# Tell kubectl to use /etc/hosts for looking up hosts

Tags: dns, kubernetes, kubectl

When executing into a pod I get following message

```
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp: lookup k8s-worker-node-a on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host
```

Is it possible to tell kubectl to use /etc/hosts to lookup machines as I have saved them inside there.

Comment: Can the API server resolve that hostname? It's insufficient for just your workstation to know the hostname, since the API server must be able to contact `kubelet` on the Node to construct the URL used to view the logs (which is what I bet you are trying)

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel This is the solution, post it as an answer so I can award it to you. Thank you very much! (But you lose your bet, I am trying to do a DNS lookup to check my if everything is working fine in my cluster ;) )

Comment: You're very kind to think of awarding the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the API server resolve that hostname? It's insufficient for just your workstation to know the hostname, since the API server must be able to contact kubelet on the Node to construct the URL used to view the logs

Turning up the verbosity of `kubectl` will show the actual handshaking that goes on between your machine, the API server, and the `kubelet` on the Node, which is how we discovered a similar misconfiguration in our cluster.